# How to get your smart contract to accept UNI Token?

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, uniswap, uni

I'm working on creating a simple contract which will receive UNI tokens from an external account and swap it for ether from UniSwap.

I'm having a very hard time understanding the documents. Can anyone please help me with how to setup the contract so that it can accept the UNI token, and I can interact with it directly in remix. I went through the interfaces written too at github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Callee.sol

But I'm not able to set it up. what is it end-to-end that I need to setup for it to receive token and make it available in the smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

the interface you need to use is IUniswapV2Router01 (im not familiar at all with v3 ngl, so if you were looking to use uniswap v3 im afraid i cant help you without doing an amount of research im definitely too lazy to do lol), not IUniswapV2Callee. Look at the `swapExactTokensForETH` function, and from there it should be pretty self explanatory. If you need more hints (or some example code) ill be glad to help :)

EDIT : this should work (i didnt test it and wrote it 100% out of memory, it might contain syntax errors)

```
// Needs IUniswapV2Router01 and IERC20 to work
IERC20 UniToken = IERC20(UniTokenAddress)
IUniswapV2Router01 router = IUniswapV2Router01(UniswapRouterAddress) // Actually both UniswapRouter01 and 02 will work, but including only UniswapRouter01 will be cheaper to deploy


function TransferAndSwap(uint256 amount) public {
// gets the tokens from msg.sender's wallet 
UniToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount) // requires allowance from msg.sender to this contract
//generates the path to make the swap
address[] memory path = new address[](2);
path[0] = address(UniToken);
path[1] = //WETH address;
//lets the contract trade 'amount' of UNI using the UniswapV2Router01
UniToken.approve(address(router), amount)
// Makes the swap 
router.swapExactTokensForETH(
    amount,
    0, // accepts any slippage, might be an issue if you're planning to make big transactions (allowing malicious actors to frontrun you), there is a workaround for that including UniswapV2Pair's getReserves functions, you should be able to figure it out ;) 
    path,
    address(this), // or any address you want, if you want to send the output ETH to another address. 
    block.timestamp
);
}
// The fallback function, to recieve  ether from the uniswapV2Router
fallback() external payable {}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, and it only takes a few lines of code to implement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.
I looked at the swap functions, but wouldn't that be the next step after receiving UNI tokens? I would like that my contract initially can receive the tokens, and assign whatever the parameters I get to public variables, do some other tasks, so I can interact with them directly in remix.
Then I can move forward with swapping. Some sample codes would really help.

Comment: Hey, indeed that would be the 2nd step after recieving the tokens (that's the "hard" part so i  assumed it was the part you were requesting help for). To have your contract interact with UNI (or any  ERC20 token), you have to integrate the IERC20 library in your code. from there you just have to tell your contract where the UNI contract lives with `IERC20 UNIToken = IERC20(//paste the uni contract address here)`, then you can call functions using `UNIToken.balanceOf(address(this))` (this is an example that lets you get the contract's UNI balance)

Comment: maybe take a look at my answer here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/106311/accepting-multiple-erc20-tokens/106314#106314, theres some more info that can help you :)

Comment: I need to interact with the transaction, eg. when we transfer ether to the contract, the fallback function is called and we can get the msg.sender property. The same way I want to implement such a function which will be called when I transfer UNI token from external account to contract. And then emit an event from that function with sender address, tokens received, etc. And store all that info. in a mapping. I read that ERC20 doesn't allow developers to handle incoming token transactions. I tried to implement IERC777Recipient, but I can't get it work

Comment: Yeah there is no such thing as a fallback function for ERC20 tokens transfers. The best way to do this imo is to ask your users to not transfer tokens directly to the contract but instead use a function of your contract that would call transferFrom from the token contract, kinda like masterchef does it (https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-farm/blob/master/contracts/MasterChef.sol (check the `deposit` function))

Comment: To test, I'll be initiating the transaction from my metamask account on ropsten network to the contract address. I'm not sure if I can transfer token from metamask to a particular function.  And also how does this method tokensReceived from IERC777Recipient works? It seems tokenReceived function must be called when the contract receives any token.

Comment: Not too familiar with the ERC777 standard, but from what i read that would require the token you're trying to send to be ERC777 itself, which isnt the case of UNI

Comment: give me a few minutes, i'll write the function you need for you (thats not really something i like doing, i prefer when people figure it out on their own, but this one is fairly simple and a good introduction for how interfacing between contract (and contract-contract interaction in general) works)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. My contract can accept the tokens whereas the swapping doesn't work. I get no error so not sure how to debug. I have kept my code here - https://github.com/SDargarh/TokenExchange-Wallet  If you could take a look into it, that would be a huge help.

Comment: mmmh.. my guess would be the problem comes from your recieve() function. Since it's not empty it could be failing assuming uniswap contracts use send() or transfer() to send ETH (those only forward 2300 gas, which isnt enough for your contract to do anything else than just recording it recieved ETH). Id update userWallet using another method, such as storing the ether balance of the contract before the swap and then calculating the difference between it and the balance after the swap.

Comment: I removed the statement from the receive function and added it right after swap, still I don't see my contract receiving any ether.

Comment: For approving my contract to receive tokens from my account I get a separate request through metamask, which I approve. As for approving the router to swap the tokens, is there something else I need to do, other than just the approve function call?

Comment: no, the approve function should be enough. Maybe you want to correct this line     `IUniswapV2Router01 public router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);` (put IUniswapV2Router02 on both sides) but it should still work like that. Do you have a failed transaction example?

Comment: I do not have a failed transaction to show, there are no errors. For my account I can see the past transactions of transfer token to contract and approve transaction too. But for my contract I only see successful receive token transaction, and no approve transaction as I see for my account.    Contract: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x00D3BD7e421DC46900169B717bdEF69aa04AdDa9          Account:https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xE79579F3F024FCCC358e19e40aaE97F019f64AB2    It's as if the approve and swap function didn't even execute.